# "Dump" hql database when running integration test

Tags: java, database, unit-testing, spring-mvc, hsqldb

I'm performing some integration test with dbunit on an in-memory HSQL database. A problem is that I don't have an user interface(like pgAdmin) to check on the data between the tests.

Does dbunit support any mean by which I can "dump" a snapshot of the HSQL database, so that I can review it after the test complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export it to an XML file, but would you not be better using DBUnit's database compare facility?

You simply craft up a file version of how the d/b should look, then compare the in-memory  database to that version.

Comment: craft up a file version seems a bit too much for me. The testing feature relates many model objects, and it will take lots of effort to create them all. In the mean time, I just need to check some specific characteristics of the data, such as the registered number must be always equals to the number of payments made.

Comment: OK, then dump the database to an XML in the closing method of your tests, and check that, or if you need only specific pieces of data, either select them & print them - or better yet, select them and assert against them in a test class

Comment: thanks. I found out about the extract function of DBUnit now. I'm gonna give it a try

Comment: Good stuff. Rather than trawl through a d/b dump by hand each time you run your tests though, would it be a better approach to do the following in your teardown code: retrieve the relevant values from the d/b and use Junit's (or whatever test library you use) assertions to definitively state what you expect to see? Then you'd get automatic feedback without having to browse the xml file by eye to determine the outcome

Comment: thanks, I'm just having quite a lot parameters for that test, so that creating and maintaining a full-fledged test is costly. It's an integration test after all. For now I just want to create a check-point to prevent recursive error..

Comment: Fair enough. If you're happy this is the solution, could you accept the answer please?